# Check if a value not exist in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to make a day_off array based on work_day array, for example is if current date doesn't exist in work_day array for each group. I want to store it into new array.

I have `work_day` array like this (1 for sunday):

```
array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => '854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750',
     'day' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => '854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750',
     'day' => 3,
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => '854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750',
     'day' => 4,
  ),
  3 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => 'f3f739d2-77fe-4e1f-b7fc-44242f52610b',
     'day' => 5,
  ),
  4 => 
  (object) array(
     'group_id' => 'f3f739d2-77fe-4e1f-b7fc-44242f52610b',
     'day' => 6,
  ),
```

What I do next is to check if current day is exist or not inside `work_day` array for each `group_id`. If it's not exists, then I want to store the `group_id` and the `date` for today.

I've tried like this:

```
$day_off = array();
        // Loop work day array
        foreach ($work_day_arr as $key => $work_hour) {
            // convert date now to numeric so I can compare it with the data from work_day array
            $day_now = date('N', strtotime($date_now));
            // If day from work_day array not equals to current day store it into day_off array. 
            // This is the right way to check if current day is exist?
            if($work_day->day != $day_now + 1){
                $data = (object) array();
                $data->attendance_group_id = $work_hour->group_id;
                $data->off_date = $date_now;

                $day_off[] = $data;
            }
        }
```

The result format of `day_off` array is something like this (this is the result from code above, still wrong because it created duplicate data) :

```
array:65 [▼
  0 => {#1610 ▼
    +"attendance_group_id": "854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750"
    +"off_date": "2022-04-14"
  }
  1 => {#1495 ▼
    +"attendance_group_id": "854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750"
    +"off_date": "2022-04-14"
  }
  2 => {#1477 ▼
    +"attendance_group_id": "854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750"
    +"off_date": "2022-04-14"
  }
  3 => {#1675 ▼
    +"attendance_group_id": "854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750"
    +"off_date": "2022-04-14"
  }
  4 => {#1676 ▼
    +"attendance_group_id": "854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750"
    +"off_date": "2022-04-14"
  }
  5 => {#1677 ▼
    +"attendance_group_id": "854b5b57-f863-4e48-ba9b-617899c64750"
    +"off_date": "2022-04-14"
  }
  6 => {#1678 ▼
    +"attendance_group_id": "f3f739d2-77fe-4e1f-b7fc-44242f52610b"
    +"off_date": "2022-04-14"
```

Comment: instead of $day_off[].. tried to change to $day_off[$date_now]

Comment: @ZeroOne I think the problem is the way I checking the date is exists or not inside `work_day` array. But I don't have any idea how to do it

Comment: Maybe `isset` or `in_array` may help you?

Comment: @Crimin4L I don't know how to use `in_array` to check if the date exists for each group_id

Comment: Your question contains contradictions. If today is not in the work_day array, then there is no group_id for today that you can store.

Answer (score 0):

Try This for checking the current date is exists or not inside `work_day` array
`in_array(date('d'),array_column($work_day, 'day'))`